# In Django, what is a good example of static files ending up in a reference loop?

Tags: django, django-1.11

Per the Django-1.11 upgrade notes re: `python manage.py collectstatic`

"Testing needs to be done to make sure that
- Static files do not end up in a reference loop
- Static files are not chained too deep (might not resolve)"

I've been trying to figure out a good example of the situation to which this is referring.

A quick example would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Take a look at this : https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/28154

Comment: so the original text is just referring to file symlinks at the file system level?

I've overridden the ManifestStaticFilesStorage class, setting max_post_process_passes to some low value (e.g. 1).

I want to know what example setup of static files I need for this post_process pass count to be exceeded.